# Unit testing custom $animate animations in karma

Tags: angularjs, animation, karma-runner

I'm trying to run a unit test that tests a custom addClass animation. No matter what I try, including running samples off the web, do custom animations run in the karma test runner. NOTE my animation code works fine in a working site. I just want to be able to generate jasmine tests for my animations.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
  basePath: '',
  frameworks: ['jasmine'],
  files: [
      'Scripts\\angular.js',
      'Scripts\\angular-animate.js',
      'Scripts\\angular-mocks.js',
      'Scripts\\animate-scr.js',
      'Scripts\\animate-test.js',
  ],
  exclude: [
  ],
  reporters: ['progress'],
  port: 9875,
  colors: true,
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
  autoWatch: true,
  browsers: ['Chrome'],
  captureTimeout: 60000,
  singleRun: false 
});
};
```

Here is my source code for the animation.

```
var counter = 0;
var testapp = angular.module('testapp', ['ngAnimate']);

    testapp.counter = 2;

    testapp.animation('.footeropen', function() {
    return {
            addClass : function(element, className) {
            testapp.counter = 3;
        }
    };
});
```

And here is my unit tests code

```
describe('Testing Animations', function() {
    beforeEach(module('testapp'));
    beforeEach(module('mock.animate'));

    it("should synchronously test the animation",
            inject(function($animate, $rootScope) {
        var element = angular.element('<div>hello</div>');
        $animate.addClass(element, 'footeropen');
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(testapp.counter).toBe(3);
    }));
});
```

Comment: please make sure that angular-animate.js is configured in karam.conf.js. otherwise your code will run with a noop implementation of $animate service.

Comment: mseemann, how is this different from the config declaration at the top of the post. Is there something else i'm missing apart from declaring the angular-animate.js in the files section.

Comment: you are right - my mistake!

Comment: what about $animate.flushNext('addClass'); ?

Answer (score 0):

Its with disappointment that I discovered that the mocked animate object actively stops custom animations on addClass() and removeClass(). The exact comment in the code is:

```
//There is no point in perform a class-based animation if the element already contains
//(on addClass) or doesn't contain (on removeClass) the className being animated.
//The reason why this is being called after the previous animations are cancelled
//is so that the CSS classes present on the element can be properly examined.
```

I have looked at running it without the mocked animate object and this causes a similar response.

So testing at this point is not possible.